# How to get id of an element of TD of a row in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a row with a  , which further have a  . how can i get that input id in a javascript function ?

Following is JSP code .
`

```
            <td colspan="2">
            <TABLE id="additionalContTable">
            <tr><td>
                Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id= "confirmationEmail1"type="text" name="email" value="">
                </td>
                </tr>
                </TABLE>
            </td>
        </tr> `
```

Also i have a Javascript function that add row in it
`$("#additionalContTable").append('<tr>'+
            '<td>Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;'+

            '<input id="confirmationEmail'+rowNo+'" type="text" name="emailRow"  /></td>' +
            '</tr>');
    rowNo = rowNo +1;`

Comment: What do you mean by how to get the id?  $("#additionalContTable") already gets the element by id.  Its the jQuery equivalent to the DOM document.getElementById('additionalContTable')

Comment: yeah i know , but i want id of that element which is inside the <TD>  1  I hove resolve it as below : -document.getElementById('additionalContTable').getElementsByTagName('input');`